# Custom action tag name can not be resolved in Activity class

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an android appliction for using SMS.I have created "MainActivity" class under com.intentpractice1 package in an application.
Form  this MainActivity Class I am calling another activity "usingImplictSms" under the same package.
For this i created intent filter for activity usingImplictSms in AndroiManifest xml file.The code is:

```
 <activity
        android:name="usingImplictSms">

        <intent-filter>            
           <action android:name="com.intentpractice1.SMS_INT"/>
           <category android:name="andoid.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>                
        </intent-filter>             

  </activity>
```

In my MainActivity class ,the code for creating intent is,

```
Intent i5= new Intent(com.intentpractice1.SMS_INT);
startActivity(i5);
```

The problem is in MainActivity class ,the error says

"com.intentpractice1.SMS_INT can not be resolved to a type."

PLEASE DO THE NEEDFUL.
THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

You can not start the activity by using actions. To start "usingImplictSms" activity from "MainActivity"

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, usingImplictSms.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have referred the link                http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/intent/android-intents-and-intent-filters-example/     for using custom intent.

Comment: Ok fine I forgot that. The problem in your code is put the action in quotations like  Intent i5= new Intent("com.intentpractice1.SMS_INT");